# How to fire an event whenever `<my-view#>` is active (i.e. comes into view)?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-starter-kit

Using Polymer Starter Kit as an example, I would like to have different `<app-toolbar>` in `<my-app>` (using property `headerType`) based on different `<my-view#>`, i.e.

```
<my-view1> => headerType = 'my-view1-header'
<my-view2> => headerType = 'my-view2-header'
```

In my `<my-app>`, I have created a property `headerType` and use `<dom-if>` to show/hide different `<app-toolbar>`.

My question is how would I always fire an event to `<my-app>` and set `headerType = my-view#-header` whenever `<my-view#>` is active (i.e. comes into view).

I have tried the polymer lifecycle, such as `ready()`, `attached()`, etc, and I understand they are only trigger during dom-related events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I eventually use the `_pageChanged` observer to call a function on `<my-view#>`. Below are the snippet of the code.

```js
_pageChanged: function(page) {
  let onLoad = function () {
    let selected = this.$.ironpages.children[page];

    if (Object.getPrototypeOf(selected).hasOwnProperty('viewSelected')) {
      selected.viewSelected();
    }
  }

  // Load page import on demand. Show 404 page if fails
  var resolvedPageUrl = this.resolveUrl('my-' + page + '.html');
  this.importHref(resolvedPageUrl, onLoad, this._showPage404, true);
},
```

Answer (score 0):

There is some example in Polymer shop template where you can execute something when the visibility of your view change with `iron-pages`.

you just need to add a property for example visible in each of your view element with Boolean type and observe that property to check whatever the view is visible or not, and then in your `iron-pages` you need to add selected-attribute property and the value is visible. check [Polymer Shop Template](https://github.com/Polymer/shop).